# Will a particle initially at rest at origin with acceleration as square of its x-coordinate ever move?

Tags: calculus, physics, kinematics

Cross posted from [Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/792071/why-does-a-particle-initially-at-rest-at-origin-with-acceleration-as-square-of-i) because this seems to mostly be a  mathematical problem.

Consider a particle such that at $t=0$ (time), $x=0$ (x-coordinate) and $v=0$ (speed). Let $a(x)=x^2$ (acceleration).

Intuitively speaking, the particle should forever be at origin. It is at origin initially, and won't move till it acquires a speed. It won't acquire a speed since at origin, acceleration would be 0.

However, $a(x)=x^2$ can be solved to get $x(t)=\cfrac{6}{t^2}$.

What mistake am I  making here?

Comment: Edit your post to include the details of how you solved for $x(t)$.

Comment: You have found one possible trajectory for a particle under this force field. $x(t) = v(t) = 0$ is another and there are infinitely many others. The trajectory the particle takes depends on its initial conditions. Obviously $x(t) = 6/t^2$ does not satisfy $x(0) = v(0) = 0$.

Comment: As is obvious, the domain of the soluton $x(t) = \frac{6}{t^2}$ does not include $t=0$. Keep in mind, existence theorems for solutions of differential equations do *not* guarantee that every solution exists for all time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While $x = \frac{6}{t^2}$ is *a* solution to the DE, it does not satisfy the given initial conditions. Notice that it's not even defined at $t = 0$, so it's impossible for $x(0) = \dot{x}(0) = 0$ to be true.

On the other hand, $x = 0$ *is* a solution to the DE, and it *does* satisfy the initial conditions. You can verify this directly through substitution.

In this system, $x = 0$ is an equilibrium solution, meaning that it's a valid solution to the DE that results in no movement. But it's an unstable equilibrium, meaning that a small perturbation to the system - e.g. starting the particle at $x = \epsilon$, or with a non-zero velocity - will cause it to travel on a completely different trajectory. This is different to stable equilibria where small perturbations give a solution that tries to return to rest at that point (it's the difference between balancing a boulder at the peak of a mountain versus the bottom of a valley).